# python discord 2 clients

Tags: python, discord.py

i make small code, but it doesn't work... can someone help me with this code?

```
import requests
from colorama import Fore
import discord
import time
client = discord.Client()
tok = "TOKEN"
token = "TOKEN"
headers = {
     'Authorization': f'{tok}'  
 }
src = requests.get('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/auth/login', headers=headers)
if src.status_code == 200:
    try:
        @client.event
        async def on_connect():
            print(f'Token founded! {Fore.GREEN}{client.user}({client.user.id}) {Fore.RESET}Token: {Fore.GREEN}{tok}')
            await client.close()
            time.sleep(1)
        client.run(tok, bot=False)
    except:
        print('wtf')
headers = {
     'Authorization': f'{token}' 
 }
src = requests.get('https://discordapp.com/api/v6/auth/login', headers=headers)
if src.status_code == 200:
    try:
        @client.event
        async def on_connect():
            print(f'Token founded! {Fore.GREEN}{client.user}({client.user.id}) {Fore.RESET}Token: {Fore.GREEN}{tok}')
            await client.close()
            time.sleep(1)
        client.run(tok, bot=False)
    except:
        print('wtf')
```

error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.run.<locals>.runner' was never awaited
  print('wtf')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback'
```

i need it, i try do client.logout but still show this error :/
i can't find any information about this error, that's why I'm writing it here. I think, you can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not call twice the same event on_connect if it already is assigned as a client event. If you want to add additional code, you should do that with the first  function.

Comment: okey ty, can i get discord token name (i mean e.g Xubiz#1187) without using this code? Using requests or anythink like that

Comment: You mean the user name of a guild? check out the discord py docs https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html